# Selecting the ID of GROUP BY based on other table value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables

**produtos**

```
|id(pk), nome|
==============
|27      Oats|
|183     Oats|
|190     Gold|
|25      Gold|
```

**representantes_precos**

```
|id(pk),idproduto(fk),preco|
============================
|1      183           13.00|
|2      190           10.00|
|3      25            15.00|
```

When i use this query

```
SELECT   ID, NOME
FROM     ( SELECT * FROM produtos) hey
GROUP BY NOME
HAVING   ( COUNT(NOME) > 0 )
```

I get the following results:

```
|id, nome|
==========
|190 Gold|
|27  Oats|
```

But what i need is this:

```
|id, nome|
==========
|190 Gold|
|183 Oats|
```

I want the ID of the Group By be the one who have the highest value on `representantes_precos` table. I tried with coalesce and sub-selects, joins and others things but had no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Ps.: Sorry about my poor english.

Comment: you do not need a HAVING statement if your count is greater than 0 because all that would mean is that it exists. Then do the below answer with MAX and it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MAX()` to find the largest `id` (when grouped by `nome`), then find rows matching that `id`:

```
SELECT id, nome
FROM produtos p
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT COALESCE(MAX(rp.idproduto), MAX(p.id))
  FROM produtos p
  LEFT JOIN representantes_precos rp ON p.id = rp.idproduto
  GROUP BY p.nome)
```

Working SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d38a/1).  Note the LEFT JOIN to allow `p` records that don't have a corresponding `rp`, and the use of COALESCE() to first find the MAX in the `rp` table, and then the `p` table if not found.

Trying to GROUP on a non-distinct column, and then including other non-grouped columns in your SELECT clause (`id` in your case), is asking for trouble.  Why MySQL permits this and then returns unpredictable results is beyond me.

Comment: This works. Thanks. But, there is a way to make this returns all registers on the produtos table even if they don't have a correspondent in the representantes_precos table?

Comment: @user2516656: If they don't have a corresponding entry in the representantes_precos table, which value should be returned - still the largest id?

Comment: If they don't have a corresponding entry any ID could be returned, but if they have only one corresponding entry, the ID of that entry should be returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   ID, NOME
FROM     ( SELECT p.ID,p.Nome,r.preco FROM produtos p
          left join representantes_precos r
          on p.id=r.idproduto order by preco desc) test
GROUP BY NOME;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d38a/12)

Comment: This is not returning the desired results, check your fiddle.  It returns the lowest id rather than the highest.  And it's also calling `ID` after grouping by `NOME` - the behavior for such a query is _unpredictable_ and should not be used.